# Create relationship foreach elements in array in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have some problem with neo4j, cypher language...

I have these types of node:
Movie

```
 {
   "overview":"An Amazon princess comes to the world of Man to become 
   the greatest of the female superheroes.",
   "actors":[
     "Gal Gadot",
     "Chris Pine",
     "Connie Nielsen",
     "Robin Wright",
     "Danny Huston"],
  "original_title":"Wonder Woman",
  "runtime":141,
  "title":"Wonder Woman"
```

}

Actor

```
{
 "birthday":"1985-04-30",
 "place_of_birth":"Rosh Ha'ayin, Israel",
 "popularity":54.444332,
 "name":"Gal Gadot"
},
```

I would create a relationship "ACTED_IN" between Actor and Movie, and I would do this for each actor in the array "actors".

This is the command:

```
MATCH (f:Movie), (a:Actors)
FOREACH (n IN f.actors | CREATE (f)-[:ACTED_IN]->(a))
```

but I don't know where to put the "WHERE CONDITION"... each elements in actors array = Actors.name.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need a `FOREACH` to do it. Change your query to:

```
MATCH (f:Movie)
UNWIND f.actors as names
MATCH (a:Actors {name:names})
CREATE (f)-[:ACTED_IN]->(a)
```

That is: `MATCH` all movies and use [UNWIND](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/unwind/) to transform the list of names into a sequence of rows. After it, `MATCH` actors by name and create the relationships between the movie and the matched actors.

Comment: Is this correct? I read it as "create relationships between the movie who ACTED_IN these actors".